# ASP to database connection

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

I am new to ASP. I have two databases production and developer databases.
I need to check developer site is going to developer database or not. Both databases have same data and same table names.
But i must work on developer database only how can I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you'd have an environment configuration file.  If you're talking about ASP.NET then it would be the Web.config file.  If you're indeed talking about classic ASP then it would probably be an included script with some constants.

If the databases are structurally identical (which they should be) then all you should need to change is the connection string.  For classic ASP, you'd probably just store it in a variable:

```
Dim connString = "This is your connection string"
```

On the production server, the connection string would be set to your production database.  On development machines, it would be set to a development database.  (And so on for a test environment, etc.)  All of the data access code would just use this connection string variable.

Even more to the point, this should not be the *only* thing that prevents a developer from using the production database.  The DBA should set the permissions such that *only* the production application has *only* the access it needs to that database and others do not.  Developers should never be able to accidentally modify the production database.  So even if you did use the production connection string from your workstation, the database should simply deny you access.

Answer (score 1):

Have two connection strings.  Then create a constant variable which will act as your switch and pick the correct connection string:

```
Dim strCon
CONST DEVELOPMENT = true

if(DEVELOPMENT = true) then
    strCon = "Development connection string"
else
    strCon = "Live connection string"
end if

adoCon.open strCon
```

Then you can simply change the switch to true/false depending on which database to pick.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify the database connection you know where you are pointing, so this should be straightforward. But it might be a good idea to use separate logins on dev and production.

So the answer is that you should use the connectionstrings in the config files to get what you need: the "database =.." setting should be set correctly and your problem is aolvedsolved To get extra certainty use different logins, which is recommendable in any case.

you can also use server tracing to monitor activity, but it is not easy on a multi user database and is only a diagnostics tool, not a cure.